# AssertJ: fluent ordering tests with custom comparator

Tags: java, assertj

Let us assume that I have a class `Foo`, which does *not* implement `Comparable` and a `FooComparator` class, which implements `Comparator<Foo>`.

Using AssertJ's fluent API, I would now assume that I could do something like this:

```
Foo foo1 = ...;
Foo foo2 = ...;
FooComparator fooComparator = ...;
assertThat(foo1).usingComparator(fooComparator).isGreaterThan(foo2);
```

Since `Foo` does not implement Comparable, `assertThat(foo1)` will return a type of `ObjectAssert<Foo>` and since `usingComparator` also returns `ObjectAssert<Foo>`, I do not have access to the `isGreaterThan` and `isLessThan` methods, which are declared in the `ComparableAssert` interface.

Is there a reason why `ObjectAssert<Foo>.usingComparator` 'only' returns `ObjectAssert<Foo>` and not `ComparableAssert<Foo>`?

I can of course rewrite the above assertion with something along the line of `assertThat(fooComparator.compare(foo1, foo2)).isGreaterThan(0)`, but the expression itself is not particularly readable and in case of failures, the generated message (*'Expecting: <-1> to be greater than: <0>'*) does not mention the actual data in foo1 and foo2 causing the assertion to fail.

Is there a way to fluently express this condition with the built-in AssertJ API without having to implement proprietary extensions or wrappers?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you can't return a `ComparableAssert<Foo>` after `usingComparator` because `AbstractComparableAssert` requires the actual type `Foo` to be `Comparable`. `AbstractComparableAssert` is declared like this:

```
AbstractComparableAssert<SELF extends AbstractComparableAssert<SELF, ACTUAL>,
                         ACTUAL extends Comparable<? super ACTUAL>>
```

I'm not sure if that will help but I will mention it anyway, you could write:

```
assertThat(asList(foo1, foo2)).isSortedAccordingTo(fooComparator);
```

Comment: That just shifts the question to be: Why does ComparableAssert require ACTUAL to implement Comparable instead of allowing assertions on a non-comparable type in connection with a suitable Comparator-implementation?

Comment: Simply because we did not think of that use case.

Comment: I have created an issue to track that improvement
https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/1492